# why i cannot invoke python script which is in the same project?

Tags: python, python-import

the project structure is as follows:

```
src
   package1
       a.py
   c.py
```

i can import c from a.py, but why there is ImportError: No module named c, when i try to run a.py?

btw, i am using pydev

**Edit 1**

the problem is not the same, i run this script from Pydev, failed:( what should i do then? 
**the src source folder is already in PYTHONPATH**, but the ImportError still exists, why?

Comment: Can you add `import sys;print sys.path` above the import?

Comment: Do not run submodules as normal programs! If you want to execute a submodule use the `-m` switch: `python -m package1.a`. Doing otherwise inevitably creates problems because running `python package1/a.py` will not consider `a.py` as a submodule of `package1`.